# Reinstall app removed via ADB

Tags: adb, system-apps, 8.1-oreo, bluetooth-audio

I removed 'MusicFX' via

```
adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 'musicfx package'
```

And now I'm having issue with playing Bluetooth media audio, so I thought maybe it's that

Can it be reinstall, maybe an ADB command? The APK is still in /system/priv-app, but trying to install from there won't work (says app not installed)

Comment: Try to install it using `adb shell pm install /system/priv-app/PATH_TO_APK` and note the error. If an error do shows up, try it again but also monitor logcat using `adb  logcat -v long`

Comment: Will do next time I have access to a pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adb shell pm install-existing com.android.musicfx
```